# link_to: undefined local variable or method 'post'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, post, haml

I don't know what I'm missing here, because the Ruby API documentation for this particular part is total garbage... I need this link_to to POST, but no matter what I do it won't take the `method: post` option.

`= link_to "Remind", "#", class: "btn green invitation-reminder", method: post`

I get the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `post' for #<#<Class:0x007f378f9cb738>:0x007f378faa2fd0>
```

I know this is probably just a goofy syntax error, but I'm still very new to Ruby and web frameworks in general, bear with me. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the *symbol* `:post` instead of the missing method `post`:

```
= link_to "Remind", "#", class: "btn green invitation-reminder", method: :post
```